# Did Errett Bishop and L.E.J. Brouwer treat the real numbers differently?

Tags: analysis, logic, real-numbers, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I know how Brouwer treated the real numbers and I know both mathematicians followed  constructive mathematics rules. 
I want to understand if there had been some some disagreement between them regarding the real numbers.

Comment: related posts : [are-all-functions-in-bishops-constructive-mathematics-continuous](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164694/are-all-functions-in-bishops-constructive-mathematics-continuous) and [did-bishop-heyting-or-brouwer-take-partial-functions-seriously](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224405/did-bishop-heyting-or-brouwer-take-partial-functions-seriously).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They treated the *continuum* differently: the differences are more on real *functions*.

You can see :

- Errett Bishop, [Foundations of constructive analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=Z7I-AAAAIAAJ) (1967), Ch.1 **A constructivist manifesto**, page 1-on,

and the introductive discussion into :

- Anne Troelstra & Dirk van Dalen, [Constructivism in mathematics: An Introduction. Volume I](https://books.google.it/books?id=-tc2qp0-2bsC&pg=PA28) (1988), page 28:

> [Bishop] cannot, like Brouwer, show that all real functions are continuous.

For an explicit criticism by Bishop of Brouwer's "metaphysical speculation", see:

- Errett Bishop & Douglas Bridges, [Constructive Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=GF8lBAAAQBAJ&pg=Pa9) (1985), page 9.

See also [Myhill's review](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2272421?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) of Bishop's book, with a summary comparison of Bishop's and Brouwer's concepts:

> An important difference is that the notion of "free choice sequence" is dropped from Bishop's mathematics and the only sequences used are lawlike ones. Another difference is that no results are stated which contradict theorems of classical mathematics; for instance, instead of the intuitionistic result that all real functions are continuous, we have the metatheorem that the only functions that can be proved to exist are provably continuous. Both these differences make the mathematics in the book look far more familiar to the classical mathematician than do Brouwer's.

---

Useful comments can be found also into :

- Michael Beeson, [Foundations of constructive mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=j6f9CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA47) (1985), Ch.III **Some Different Philosophies of Constructive Mathematics**, page 47-on.

And see also [Constructive Mathematics](http://www.math.canterbury.ac.nz/php/groups/cm/faq/).

Comment: I find it quite hard to understand, do you have a simple example that shows exactly the point that thier observation to the real functions is changing ? I am getting that Bishopp stand as neutral between classical and intuitistic math. I don't really understand if he, as brouwer, thinks that every real function is continuous.

Comment: Bishop's system is consistent with all real functions being continuous, but is also consistent with classical mathematics. Brouwer claimed a prove that all real functions are continuous, so his system would not be consistent with classical mathematics.

Comment: Does bishopp's real number defenition follows the law of trichometry ?

Comment: @NotSure: trichotomy is not provable in Bishop's system, nor in any of the usual systems of constructive mathematics.  In the end, trichotomy should be viewed as a property of the reals that is closely tied to classical logic.

Comment: @CarlMummert I believe he meant all computable real functions are continuous, which holds in classical mathematics.

Comment: @Tony: for Brouwer, he actually claimed that all functions are continuous.  This is discussed in the Stanford Encyclopedia entry, https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/ . It is one key way that Brouwer's intuitionism is incompatible with classical mathematics, unlike Bishop's system that was compatible with both classical and constructive reasoning.

Comment: @Carl Mummert The article does not say in what sense the approach is incompatible. As far as I understand Brouwer only showed that computable functions are continuous, which classical mathematics also proves. Since there is no evidence that other functions exist, Brouwer concludes all functions are continuous. Seems more a disagreement on a definition than an incompatibility?

Comment: "Besides the rejection of the principle of the excluded middle, intuitionism strongly deviates from classical mathematics in the conception of the continuum, which in the former setting has the property that all total functions on it are continuous. Thus, unlike several other theories of constructive mathematics, intuitionism is not a restriction of classical reasoning; it contradicts classical mathematics in a fundamental way." Here they mean Brouwer's intuitionism in particular. Brouwer would not have agreed that all functions on the reals are computable.